# Flutter - Cloudinary how to get uploaded image url?

Tags: flutter, dart, cloudinary

I am uploading my image in cloudinary

```
final res = await cloudinary.uploadFile(
        CloudinaryFile.fromFile(
          _pickedFile.path,
          folder: 'hello-folder',
          context: {
            'alt': 'Hello',
            'caption': 'An example image',
          },
        ),
      );
      print('my res *** $res');
```

after upload image it's print res of
result

```
my res *** {asset_id: adasdasdasdasd, public_id: hello-folder/asdasdasd, created_at: 2021-08-27 20:04:45.000Z, url: http://res.cloudinary.com/dqunmzmqo/image/upload/v1630094685/hello-folder/d2eoasynxhj5llhb1p9e.jpg, secure_url: https://res.cloudinary.com/dqunmzmqo/image/upload/v1630094685/hello-folder/d2eoasynxhj5llhb1p9e.jpg, original_filename: 6b81c53d-7602-4bea-9ea1-1eaef1491144, tags: [], context: {custom: {alt: Hello, caption: An example image}}}
```

i want to get url from res variable

Comment: I think response will be like `{"asset_id": "adasdasdasdasd",.......}`. is missing double quote?

Answer (score 0):

**For Those Who Looking For Correct Answer**

```
final res = await cloudinary.uploadFile(
        CloudinaryFile.fromFile(
          _pickedFile.path,
          folder: 'hello-folder',
          context: {
            'alt': 'Hello',
            'caption': 'An example image',
          },
        ),
      );
    

Try this print(res.secureUrl)
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.